# Add a way to link to the /tags page with a tag search prefilled

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, tags-page

I'd like to link to https://ai.stackexchange.com/tags with tag search = "gpt" prefilled:

[image]

Can that be realized?

Comment: Pretty sure it's not possible, but that's a nice feature request.

Comment: I agree with @Shadow - I hope you don't mind I converted it into a FR.